# unable to update Parent Fields from Child in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

I got 2 objects Contacts(Parent) and Survey custom Object(Child). All I'm trying to do is update a field of contact object from child.

```
Survey_Response__c AvailSurveys =  [select name,Contact__c,Contact__r.id,Contact__r.Name,Contact__r.All_Survey_Responses__c  ,Response__c from Survey_Response__c];

List<Survey_Response__c> SurvyList = new List<Survey_Response__c>();

for(Survey_Response__c survy : AvailSurveys ) {
  if(survy.Contact__c != null) {
        if(survy.Contact__r.All_Survey_Responses__c != null) {
            survy.Contact__r.All_Survey_Responses__c = survy.Contact__r.All_Survey_Responses__c +','+ survy.Response__c ;
        }
        else survy.Contact__r.All_Survey_Responses__c = survy.Response__c ;
   }
   SurvyList.add(survy);           
}         

update SurvyList;
```

Parent field is not updating in this scenario.Any help?

Comment: from what I see you are not querying the Survey_Response__c.id in your select statement.

Comment: is it master-detail or lookup relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you're not actually updating the `Contact` records but instead updating the `Survey_Response__c` records. To update the contacts you'll need to store a list of the `Contact` records and update that rather than the current `SurvyList` as you are currently doing it. 
I have quickly put together a version which stores and updates the contacts below with comments to explain any changes made:

```
Survey_Response__c AvailSurveys =  [select name,Contact__c,Contact__r.id,Contact__r.Name,Contact__r.All_Survey_Responses__c  ,Response__c from Survey_Response__c];

Map<Id,Contact> contactsToUpdate = new Map<Id,Contact>();
for(Survey_Response__c survy : AvailSurveys )
{
    if(survy.Contact__c != null)
    {
    /*
    *   Because we may have multiple surveys referencing the same contact put the contacts into a map keyed by id
    *   this will help when updating to avoid duplicate contacts in the update list and will help stop unwanted overwriting of All_Survey_Responses__c data.
    */
        if(!contactsToUpdate.containsKey(survy.Contact__c))
        {
            contactsToUpdate.put(survy.Contact__c, survy.Contact__r);
        }
        Contact currentContact = contactsToUpdate.get(survy.Contact__c);

        /*
        *   Now we have the current contact we will be working on that record from here out in the loop.
        */
        if(currentContact.All_Survey_Responses__c != null)
        {
            currentContact.All_Survey_Responses__c = currentContact.All_Survey_Responses__c +','+ survy.Response__c ;
        }
        else currentContact.All_Survey_Responses__c = survy.Response__c ;
        system.debug('survy -->'+survy );
    }           
}     
/*
* if we have contacts added to the map update these to store the new   All_Survey_Responses__c values.
*/
if(contactsToUpdate.size() > 0)
{    
    /*
    *   as its a map we're calling update against the list of values in the map.
    */
    update contactsToUpdate.values();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't update `Contact__r` this way. All changes made to `Contact__r` will we be erased on survy `update`. What you should do is to collect the `Contact__r` objects and update them separately.

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship happens to be **master-detail**, select the field and check ***Child records can be reparented to other parent records after they are created*** to allow updating a specific record.